# mongoexport in php with query

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb

I used mongoexport to export my db records in a file

```
mongoexport --db foo --collection data --jsonArray  --query '{ 
        "ts": { 
          "$gte": { "$date": "2021-05-28T00:00:00.001Z" },
          "$lte": { "$date": "2021-06-10T23:59:59.000Z" }
        }
      }'   --out final.json
```

I am trying to run the same command in my PHP code but the $ sign is giving problems as expected. I used slashes but that too is not working.

Comment: The `mongoexport` runs from operating system command-line. How are you trying it from php?

Comment: @prasad_ any cli command can be run from PHP code. you can use system(), exec() for the same.

Comment: Thats correct (I have tried it in Java and it works).

Comment: @prasad_ yeah it might be but as the $ sign is used for declaring a variable, it is giving issues in PHP :(

Comment: Not sure I understand your concern.